# Using form how to send payload for POST as JSON

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am using HTML  to download xlsx,pdf files using POST call. 
  I am using the below code to send my payload but it is sending as url format,

```
 <form method="post" action="{{url}}" enctype='application/json'>
<input type="text" name="type" value="{{type}}" hidden>
<input type="text" name="paramValue" value="{{value}}" hidden>
</form>


Request body
type=Shop&paramValue=Kumar
```

I need to pass it as JSON because of this I am getting an error as,

```
Response    HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

Please suggest how to pass the data as JSON in case of using form in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Form `enctype` attribute does not support `application/json` as seen [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_form_enctype.asp).

You need to manually json encode your data to use with your post request or use the `$http` service which posts json by default:

```
var data = { type: $scope.form.type, value: $scope.form.value };

$http.post(url, data) // default content-type is 'application/json' for $http.post
.success(function(data, status) {
  //yay
});
```

Comment: Using $http it is a seperate Angular call, I can't use it with form action, where it required to pass the url with $http, but I need to construct JSON in form and action. Please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: You cannot do it with a plain form. You need JavaScript to serialize into Json and set request header content-type. That said, you can use onsubmit or onclick with angular to call into your controller or use jquery, but it is impossible with vanilla HTML forms